# A network-related or instance-specific error Only in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql

I am getting “A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)” Error when connection throw ASP.NET ONLY . **if I try to connect windows application I am able to connect and retrieve values.**
I am unable to find any solution 
Thanks

Comment: What credentials are you providing with the connection string?

Comment: am able to ping it; i double checked my firewall i also added firewall exception; my sql server is in a local machine; no firewall in that machine(i removed all);

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the simplest things can be the trickiest to discover. I would check to ensure nothing as simple as a typo exists in the name of the SQL Server provided to the ASP.NET application. Make sure that value does, in fact, match that supplied to the Windows application.

If the name is verified correct, I would then make sure that the outbound connection from the ASP.NET application isn't inadvertently trying to go through a proxy server.

Comment: It is a MVC 3 application that make any probleam?

Comment: Really shouldn't make any difference. Sounds very much like a basic connectivity issue to me.